# How to find start and end of IF THEN ELSE block in asp classic

Tags: asp-classic, ide

I have been tasked to edit some classic asp pages(though I develop in C#). These were created 10 years back but are still in use. One of the file is very big spanning 5159 lines. It has got many nested if then conditions which I am unable to figure out .. which is this if , where it is starting or where next if is like that.

I have tried vs2010 but it also dosen't highlight start/end of if/else, I tried notepad++ also with the same story.

My question to asp developers is that which IDE they use or how they figure out the start of  many nested ifs thens?

Answer (score 1):

I like to use UltraEdit Professional Text/HEX Editor which can fold unfold blocks: http://www.ultraedit.com/

Also this could help: http://www.aspindent.com/?indent

Never used it but heared good things about it: http://www.aspdebugger.com/

Answer (score 1):

A code folding feature is very helpful on such problems, but only if code is quite good formatted. But code folding is of no help if the nesting takes place within a line.

All IDE and most text editors have a ***Match Brace*** command or something similar. That command is usually best to find the matching brace of a condition in a not well formatted block with nested conditions.

UltraEdit and maybe also other text editors support even customizable strings which are applied to the ***Match Brace*** feature. Perhaps this is a help for you on the not well structured ASP code.

UltraEdit has several brace matching features. But for your problem the most helpful would be the commands **Go to Matching Brace** and **Select to Matching Brace** which are both in menu **Search** (traditional menus) respectively **Go to brace** and **Select to brace** on **Codding** tab/menu (ribbon mode/contemporary menus). With caret blinking at beginning of an `If` the first command moves caret to the matching `End If` and the second command additionally selects everything from `If` to `End If`. The commands can be used also in reverse direction from `End If` to matching `If`.

But before the brace matching commands can be used on your ASP files on `If` and `End If`, it is necessary to define the string `If` as opening brace and the string `End If` as closing brace in the syntax highlighting wordfile for ASP.

To do this open in UltraEdit from ribbon/menu **Advanced** the **Configuration** by clicking on **Configuration** (traditional menus) or **Settings** (ribbon mode/contemporary menus). Open in configuration tree **Editor Display** and click on **Syntax Highlighting**. Select the language respectively wordfile **VBScript ASP** and click on button **Open**. Exit the configuration dialog with button **Cancel**.

In the opened wordfile **vbscript.uew** search at top for the lines

```
/Open Brace Strings = "{" "(" "[" "<"
/Close Brace Strings = "}" ")" "]" ">"
```

and append on first line `"If"` and on second line `"End If"`.

```
/Open Brace Strings = "{" "(" "[" "<" "If"
/Close Brace Strings = "}" ")" "]" ">" "End If"
```

Save the modified wordfile and close it. The modification is immediately active and you can use now the commands **Go to** *Matching* **Brace** and **Select to** *Matching* **Brace** in your ASP files.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how to add If / End if to the word list of UltraEdit. However, UltraEdit was not able to match the closing End If I was looking for in a large file, probably due to the fact that there are many If statements consisting of just "If" and "Then", and no "End If", which is also allowed in vbscript/classic asp, if you write it on a single line.

Comment: Addition to my previous comment: After adding End If to all single line If statements in my classic asp file, UltraEdit still had problems; it didn't find the End If from a starting If, but managed to find the opposite, when I placed the cursor on one of the End Ifs.

Comment: @AndreasJansson The match brace feature requires that there is an `End If` for each `If`. Otherwise it cannot work because it is designed mainly for __brace__ matching. It is interesting that reverse search for matching `If` on caret at `End If` works, but not the normal search direction in your case with the large file. The large file could be interesting for me or the developers of UltraEdit for investigation. Is it possible for you to upload the file as a public attachment in a ZIP or RAR archive in UltraEdit forums or send it private by email to IDM support?

Comment: Thanks... but I'm sorry, I didn't keep the file where I added End If to all single line If statements. Perhaps I hadn't found them all either; now that I'm done with it I don't remember whether it was the correct "If" that was found by UltraEdit when selecting "in reverse".
After re-indenting the whole file manually, searching for every If and its corresponding End If we finally managed to deal with the file.